# PhpStorm shows different colors for the same methods

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, color-scheme, facade

Well, it's not a big deal and does not look like a real problem. But, I'm just wondering why does PhpStorm show the same methods in different colors?

[image: Look at this picture for better understanding.]

As you see, the same methods (`Auth::User()`) have different colors (some are orange and some are yellow). Why?

PS: My PhpStorm color scheme is set as default. That's on **Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Language Defaults**.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see it has to be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28835

Watch that ticket (star/comment/vote) to get notified on any progress.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this method is declared with the @method PHPDoc tag?
It's a bug, please leave your vote here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28835